# How to bind to a property in some other component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular. This is the first time I'm trying something like this. I don't know whether it is doable or not.

I have an `Apply` button in `Timeselector` (my custom component) which is enabled or disabled on the basis of validation happening in `Monthpicker` (my another custom component). Right now I'm doing this:

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="apply()" [disabled]="!isValid">
```

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
isValid: boolean= true;
...
@ViewChild(MonthpickerComponent) monthpicker: MonthpickerComponent;
...
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isValid=this.monthpicker.isValidRange;  
}
```

But this happens on `ngOnInit` only. There's no other method which is called from monthpicker. What should I do?

Here's my **monthpicker.component.ts**

```
isValidRange: boolean= true;
...
validate(sDate: string, eDate: string) {
    this.isValidRange=true;
    ...
    if (...) {
        this.isValidRange=false;
    }
    if (...) {
        this.isValidRange=false;
    }
    if (//all good) {
        this.isValidRange=true;
    }
}
```

`isValidRange` is set to `true` based on some conditions. Is there anyway that I can bind that apply button directly to `isValidRange`? Is it possible:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="apply()" [disabled]="monthpicker.!isValidRange">
```

If this question needs more details then please let me know. I'll quickly create a stackblitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with Angular things but with JavaScript syntax.

`!` operator cannot be used directly on the property. You need to place `!` on the very left of the variable name.

Try `[disabled]="!monthpicker.isValidRange"`.

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="apply()" [disabled]="!monthpicker.isValidRange">
```

Comment: Ok. Let me run test cases. I'll get back to you. Thanks man . :-)

Comment: It is working. Can you please me explain how. Because my tech lead will definitely cross-question. Thank you. :-)